# How to stop iPhone from offloading ebooks?

Tags: iphone, ios, books

Sometimes I download ebooks in the Books app on my iPhone 7 running the latest iOS.

And then when I try to read them later without internet connection... I cannot

How can I force them to stay on my device so that I can read them when I am offline?

Comment: Are you downloading the ebooks to your iCloud storage or directly to your iPhone?

Comment: @agarza often I just airdrop a .epub to myself and choose Open with Books on the iPhone. I have the same problem with Books Store downloads though.